# Norm of linear functional definition

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis

For a normed linear space $X$.

Define norm of bounded linear functional $T$ as inf of value of $M$ such that:

$\|T(f)\| \le M \|f\|$

Prove that $\|T\|_\star = \sup\{T(f):f\in X,\|f\|\le 1\}$.

My attempt:

First since we have $\|T(f)\| \le \|T\|_\star\|f\|\le \|T\|_\star$ we have $\|T\|_\star$ is upper bound.

To show it's least, since for any $f$ with $\|f\|\ne 0$ we have a $g = \frac{f}{\|f\|}$ with same bound $M$.Hence we just need to consider the function with $\|f\| = 1$ in X with same set of $M$.hence by definition of inf, we have $\|T\|_\star$ is the sup for $\{T(f):f\in X,\|f\|\le 1\}$.

My question is is there some more elegant proof for this result.
Or much more intuitive proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For  the second part there is no need to introduce $g$. Let $M <\|T\|_{*}$. We have to show that the inequality $\|Tf\|\leq M\|f\|$ cannot hold. If it holds then, by definition of supremum of a set, we get some $f$ such that $M<\|Tf\|$ and $\|f\|\leq 1$. But then  $M <\|Tf\| \leq M\|f\| \leq M$ which leads to the contradiction $M<M$.